# How to check a folder contains .csv files?

Tags: php

I need to check whether a folder contains csv files or not. Using PHP

I need to show an error message if someone try to upload any csv into a specific folder if there is already existing a csv.

Comment: file_exists($csv_file_name_with_path) - http://php.net/manual/tr/function.file-exists.php

Comment: I do not want to check the file name.. say "a.csv"  is there in the folder, then if I try to upload "b.csv" it has to show an error message "CSV file is present"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `glob()` to find all files matching a wildcard. It returns an array of the matches, so you can check if the array is empty.

```
$files = glob("$dirname/*.csv");
if (!empty($files)) {
    die("Error: The directory already has a .csv file");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$filename = '/path/to/foo.txt';

if (file_exists($filename)) {
    echo "Die Datei $filename existiert";
} else {
    echo "Die Datei $filename existiert nicht";
}
?>
```

From: http://php.net/manual/de/function.file-exists.php

Comment: He wants to look for *any* CSV, not just one with the same name being uploaded.

Answer (score 0):

Loop over the files of directory to check whether it contains csv or not.

```
$files=scandir("/path/to/dir");
foreach($files as $fileName)
{
    if(preg_match("/\.csv$/", $fileName))
    {
        throw new Exception("/path/to/dir contains csv file with filename: $fileName");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$dir = 'folder';
echo (count(glob("$dir/*.csv")) === 0) ? 'Empty' : 'Not empty';
```

You can use glob() function. http://php.net/manual/tr/function.glob.php

Also @Barmar answer is look like doing job well.

Answer (score 0):

> `<?php`
>
> `$directory = new DirectoryIterator(__DIR__);`
>
> `if ($fileinfo->isFile()) {`
>
> `$fileExt = $fileinfo->getExtension();`
>
> `if($fileExt=="csv")
>      {`
>       `echo "File found";`
>    `}
>     else
>     {`
>        `echo "File not found";`
>    `}`
>
> `}`
>
> `?>`

Reference:[http://php.net/manual/en/directoryiterator.getextension.php]